# selenium located by xPath is different from different driver

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium, treeview, webdriver

I use firefox webdriver before , but now I change IE for my webdriver

I have a tree View on the WebPage,

I located the item by xPath,

but two different kinds of driver locate two different item while using the same xPath.

how to solve this problem??

And the treeView node has id , but why I locate by id is failed???

her is the treeview item i want to click :

1.

id:        uwtUserFunTree_1_4

xPath using firefox :          //div[2]/div[7]/span[3]

2.

id:uwtUserFunTree_1_4_1

xPath using firefox :          //div[8]/div/span[3]

Comment: You should put example of the xpath without example its hard to provide an answer.

Comment: i edit and show the id and xpath.

Comment: wheres the html code? We can't help you without the html. Also it seems like both locators are distinct and should work from your description.Show us the html if you want help

Comment: Is it because tree view is rendered differently in different browsers? Or the order of rows is differently sorted?

Comment: First of all the id's you have there are different! 1--> 1_4 & 2--> 1_4_1..as the other guys mentioned show the html code..but assuming that id=uwtUserFunTree_1_4_1 then your xpath should look something like this `driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@id='uwtUserFunTree_1_4_1']")` send the html code or use firefox add-on called firebug to right click and inspect the element and I'll show exactly how the xpath should be to work on both browsers..